# What is the fastest way to rotate a geometric vector?

Tags: c++, performance, math, optimization, geometry

I want to find the fastest way to rotate a 2D geometric vector by angle theta.

My current implementation uses rotation matrix math and is slow:

```
Vec2 rotate(Vec2 point, float theta)
{
    float c = std::cos(theta);
    float s = std::sin(theta);

    Vec2 result =
    {
        point.x * c - point.y * s,
        point.x * s + point.y * c
    };

    return result;
}
```

Is there a more efficient solution (I'm willing to sacrifice some accuracy)?

Comment: Trig functions can be pretty slow. You can sometimes get improvements by pre-calculating fixed-size tables of sin and cos results, and then doing an interpolated lookup.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is the way to go. And when you try to optimize your code, use a profiler and address the biggest bottlenecks in your code first it probably will not be this function, but could well be : some missed branch predictions, memory access resulting in cache misses etc.. Do not prematurely optimize bits of code you "think" are the issue. Always measure

Comment: @paddy Yes that too

Comment: Consider rephrasing the question to "a faster way", since _the_ fastest way is not really answerable.

Comment: What do you need the rotation for? Can you store a pre-baked `(c,s)` vector?

Comment: Matrix is more efficient when we have multiple transformation because we could combine them eg we want `scale (MS) > translate (MT) > rotate (MR) vector (V)` it could done by `MR * MT * MS * V = V'`  but with matrix property that we could combine them let `MR * MT * MS = T` so `T * V = V'`  keep in mind we always have operation with bulk vector.

Comment: Well, in 2-d it’s equivalent to multiplication by a complex number of unit modulus. But I suspect that will do the same operations “under the hood”.

Comment: for small angles `sin` and `cos` can be approximated by rather simple polynomials

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai And for larger angles, you can divide the angle by 4 before using the polynomial approximations: `sin(x) = 4 * sin(x/4) * cos(x/4) * (cos(x/4)**2 - sin(x/4) **2)` and `cos(x) = 2 * (2 * cos(x/4) ** 2 - 1)**2 - 1`

Answer (score 6):

I do not have the reputation to comment, so I comment here.

Instead of an angle, store in an array `θx2`, an unitary vector `cos(θ),sin(θ)` in each row. By multiplying by that vector, you will rotate by an angle `θ`.

You probably can pass the vector as parameter instead of the angle, so you do not need to make the calculation.

It depends on the rest of your code, but generally, thinking in terms of angles is more complicated and expensive than thinking in terms of unitary vectors. Try to not use explicit angles at all, so you do not need to make conversions.
It is also easier when generalizing to 3D, and has less corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to optimize for work-efficiency:

- If you are rotating millions of vectors with same angle, then you can embed the rotation into the reading part of vectors so whenever you read a vector, it is already in registers of CPU so rotation is fast, without thrashing cache of CPU.
- If you are rotating millions of vectors with multiple (but same) rotations, then it is better to multiply the matrices together as a final single rotation and then rotate the vectors only once by that single total rotation.
- If millions of rotated vectors are to be computed with some common vector only once, then just rotate that common vector instead, it's like rotating the camera when you need to rotate whole world.
- If somehow using polar coordinates or spherical coordinates is ok, then it's only made of adding/subtracting angle values without any multiplications.

---

There are also hardware-based optimizations:

- SSE/AVX vectorized code or simply OpenCL-kernel for CPU (multiple multiplications at once per core)
- CUDA/OpenCL/Compute-shader(such as in Vulkan) for GPU